# null values displaying in previous view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I have a series of `UITableViewController`s and `UIViewController`s with segues navigating away from them, when I unwind back to them, or navigate back to them, I find that the values in their labels have changed values.

Either `null` for strings, or a large integer/float (roughly 918x.xx) instead of the intended, smaller value.

However, when I refresh the view (each of them have AFNetworking implementation), everything goes back to normal. Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: My guess is that when another view covers your first view the internal memory (or variables) got messed up. My suggestion would be to put the initialization in `viewDidAppear:` or `viewWillAppear` function, depending on whether you want to animate it or not instead of in the `initWithNibName:bundle:`. It works fine with my app :)

Comment: I have tables reloading and networking calls done everytime I have viewwillappear, so I'm not sure why it would happen, since all of my labels are reset when my afnetworking requests are completed.

Comment: are you using asynchronous requests? Asynchronous requests are non-blocking and it won't reset the labels immediately. Not until they receive their responses. Have you tried re-initialize the label values before sending the requests?

Comment: I'm using AFHTTPSessionManager, looking into building a Singleton extension